# PHP warning Access denied for user and A link to the server could not be established

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, http-headers

I have a `POST` request to `PHP` file on my server, but i've got a **warning** from `PHP` and `mysql` like below :

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /path/db.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /path/db.php on line 12

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/db.php:12) in /path/inc.php on line 64
```

**DB.php**

```
<?php
define("_db","db_name");
define("_host","localhost");
define("_user","db_user");
define("_pass","db_password");
?>
```

**inc.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$d=date("l, d-F-Y");
$func="";
$CurrentLang="en";
$encoding="utf-8";
define("_secret_","MoonLight");
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
$icons_folder ="icons/";    
define('allowed_tags','<IFRAME><FORM><INPUT><TEXTAREA><A><ABBR><ACRONYM><ALIGN><AREA><B><BASE><BASEFONT><BIG><BLINK><BLOCKQUOTE><BODY><BR><CAPTION><CENTER><CITE><CODE><COL><COLGROUP><COMMENT><DD><DEL><DFN><DIR><DIV><DL><DT><EM><FIELDSET><FONT><H1><H2><H3><H4><H5><H6><HEAD><HR><I><ILAYER><IMG><INS><KBD><LABEL><LAYER><LEGEND><LI><LINK><LISTING><MAP><MARQUEE><MENU><MULTICOL><NOBR><NOLAYER><NOSAVE><OL><OPTGROUP><OPTION><P><PARAM><PRE><Q><RP><RT><RTC><RUBY><S><SAMP><SMALL><SPACER><SPAN><STRIKE><STRONG><SUB><TABLE><TBODY><TD><TFOOT><TH><THEAD><TITLE><TR><TT><U><UL><VAR><WBR><XMP>');
//_____________________________________________________________________________________
function secure($data){
    global $mysqli;
    if(is_object($data)){
        foreach($data as $k=>$v) $data->$k=secure($v);
    }
    elseif(is_array($data)){
        foreach($data as $k=>$v) $data[$k]=secure($v);
    }
    else{
        $data=strip_tags($data,allowed_tags);
        //$data=$mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($data,allowed_tags));
    }
    return $data;
}
//_____________________________________________________________________________________
function addSlash($str){
    return preg_replace_all("/([^\])'/","$1\'",$str);
}
//_____________________________________________________________________________________
//$data  = isset($_REQUEST['data'])  ? $_REQUEST['data']  : "{}";
$_GET=secure($_GET);
$_POST=secure($_POST);
$_REQUEST=secure($_REQUEST);
//_____________________________________________________________________________________


include("db.php");
include("lang_".$CurrentLang.".php");

include("dbmgr.php");
include("functions.php");
$script=strtolower(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
$dbmgr=new DbMgr(_host,_user,_pass,_db,false);   
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$mode=isset($_POST['mode'])?$_POST['mode']:"";
$_id=isset($_POST['_id'])?$_POST['_id']:"";

if(!empty($_GET)) extract($_GET);
if(!empty($_POST)) extract($_POST);

if(!isset($table)) $table="";
if(!empty($_id) && empty($mode)) $mode="s";

define("ie",strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "MSIE")?1:0);

function cutString($str, $nbChars){
    $s=mb_substr($str,0,$nbChars,'utf-8');
    $pos=mb_strrpos($s,' ','utf-8');
    if(mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8')>$nbChars) $s=mb_substr($s,0,$pos,'utf-8');
    $s.=mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8')>$nbChars?'...':'';
    return $s;
}

function getIframeUrl($iframe_string){
    preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $iframe_string, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['uid']) && preg_match('/tbl_/',$script) && $_SESSION['ugroup']<>1){
    // get script name
    $sql = sprintf("select * from v_user_perm where user_id=%s and funcfile='%s';",$_SESSION['uid'],$script);
    $result=$dbmgr->query($sql);
    if(!$row=$dbmgr->next($result)){
        header("Location: 403.php");
    }
}
//_____________________________________________________________________________________
function sendEmail($from, $to, $subject, $body){
    require_once('dSendMail2.inc.php');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);   
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $m = new dSendMail2;
    $m->setTo($to);
    $m->setFrom($from);
    $m->setSubject($subject);
    $m->setMessage($body);
    // EXACTLY THE SAME CODE as any other example.. Except for the line below:
    //$m->sendThroughSMTP("mail.example.co", 25, "example@example.co", "Ul5JeniQ6RWT");
    // Real GMail example:
    //$m->sendThroughSMTP("bit.bit1.me", 465, $from, "Info_2016", true);
    $m->sendThroughSMTP("bit.bit1.me", 465, "example@example.co", "Ul5JeniQ6RWT", true);
    // You can still send mass mails, attachments, embedded images... Do what you want!
    $m->send();
    return $m;
}
//_____________________________________________________________________________________
?>
```

**dbmgr.php**

```
    <?php
    /*
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |* Class DbMgr ***************************************************************|
    |* A Class to manage Databases 
*******************************|
    |* Creation Date: 26-07-2010 (Version 1.0) ***********************************|
    |* Licence: LGPL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) **********************|
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    */
    define("MYSQLI_OBJ","MYSQLI_OBJ");
    class DbMgr
    {
        var $host;
        var $user;
        var $pass;
        var $db;
        var $mysqli;
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
        {
            $this->host = $host;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->pass = $pass;
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
            if($this->mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
                die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
            }
            $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function __destruct()
        {
            $this->closeDB();
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function closeDB()
        {
            @$this->mysqli->close();
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function select($fields = "*", $t,$filter=1,$sort="",$dir="" ,$start=0,$limit=0, $grid=true)
        {
            $q = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM `" . $t . "` WHERE " . $filter;
            $count = $limit;
            if($grid){
                if(!$result = $this->query($q)) return $this->mysqli->error;
                $count = $result->num_rows;
            }
            if (!empty($sort)) $q .= " ORDER BY " . $sort . " " . $dir;
            if($limit>0) $q.= " LIMIT " . $start . "," . $limit;
            //if (!empty($sort) || $limit>0) 
            //echo $q;
                if(!$result = $this->query($q)) return $this->mysqli->error;
            return array('result'=>$result, 'count'=>$count);
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function insert($t, $data)
        {
            $sql="insert into `".$t."` (";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $sql.="`$key`,";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1);
            $sql.=") values (";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $sql.="'".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($value)."' ,";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1);
            $sql.=");";
            if($result=$this->query($sql)){
                $this->last_id=$this->mysqli->insert_id;
            return $result;
            }
        return false;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function pk($t)
        {
            if($res=$this->query("SHOW KEYS FROM `$t` WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")){
                if($row = $this->next($res)) return $row['Column_name'];
            }
            return '';
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function exists($t)
        {
            return (@$this->mysqli->query("select 1 from `$t`"))?true:false;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function delete($t, $ids)
        {
            return $this->query("DELETE FROM `" . $t . "` WHERE `".$this->pk($t)."` in ('". $ids ."')");
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function update($t,$id,$data)
        {
            $sql="UPDATE `" . $t . "` SET ";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $sql.="`$key`='".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($value)."' ,";
            }
            $sql=substr($sql,0,-1);
            $sql.=" WHERE `".$this->pk($t)."`='".$id."'";
            //echo $sql;
            return $this->query($sql);

        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function query($q)
        {
            //echo $q;
            if($result=$this->mysqli->query($q)){
                return $result;        
            }
            else{
                //echo $q;
                $this->error=$this->mysqli->error;
            }
            //echo $this->mysqli->error;
            return false;        
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function next($result,$type=MYSQLI_ASSOC)
        {
            switch($type){
                case MYSQLI_OBJ:
                    return $result->mysql_fetch_object();
                    break;
                default:
                    //echo $this->SqlQuery;
                    return $result->fetch_array($type);
                    break;
            }
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function Err($table,$fields,$err){
                foreach($fields as $v){
                    $err=str_replace($v, constant("lbl_".$table."_".$v), $err);
                }
                return $err;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function crud($table, &$mode,$ssql,$isql,$esql,$xsql,&$_id,&$row, $fields){
            switch($mode){
                case "u":
                    if($reslt=$this->query($esql)){
                        Message(msg_updated);
                    }
                    else{
                        Message($this->Err($table, $fields,$this->error));
                    }
                    break;
                case "i":
                    if($reslt=$this->query($isql)){
                        $_id=$this->mysqli->insert_id;
                        Message(msg_inserted);
                        foreach($fields as $v) unset($$v);
                        $mode="";
                    }
                    else{
                        Message($this->Err($table, $fields,$this->error));
                    }
                    break;
                case "x":
                    if($reslt=$this->query($xsql)){
                        Message(msg_deleted);
                    }
                    else{
                        Message($this->Err($table, $fields,$this->error));
                    }
                    break;
                case "c":
                case "s":
                    if($reslt=$this->query($ssql)){
                        $row = $this->next($reslt);
                        foreach($row as $k=>$v) $row[$k]=stripslashes($v);
                    }
                    else{
                        Message($this->Err($table, $fields,$this->error));
                    }
                    if($mode=="c") $_id="";
                         $mode=$mode=="c"?"i":"u";
                    break;
                default:
                    $mode="i";
                    break;
            }
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function SP_Exists($p)
        {
            $f = array();
            $sql="SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS";
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            while ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                if($row['Name']==$p) return true;
            }
            return false;
            return $f;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function DatabasesNamesAsArray()
        {
            $f = array();
            $sql="SHOW databases;";
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            while ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                array_push($f, current($row));
            }
            return $f;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function TablesNamesAsArray($db)
        {
            $f = array();
            $sql="SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db;
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            while ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                array_push($f, current($row));
            }
            return $f;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function Fields($table, $detail = true)
        {
            $f = array();
            $sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" . $table . "`;";
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            while ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                array_push($f, $detail ? $row : $row['Field']);
            }
            return $f;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function gridFields($table)
        {
            $f = array();
            $sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" . $table . "`;";
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            while ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                //array_push($f, $row['Type']=='text'? 'LEFT('.$row['Field'].',10)' : $row['Field']);
                if($row['Type']!='text') array_push($f,$row['Field']);
            }
            return implode(",", $f);
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function FieldsNamesAsArray($table)
        {
            return $this->Fields($table, false);
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function FieldsNamesAsString($table)
        {
            return implode(",", $this->FieldsNamesAsArray($table));
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function all($res) {
            $r=array();
            while($row=$this->next($res)){
                array_push($r,$row);
            }
            return $r;
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
        function parseSetEnum($table,$name){
            $sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table` LIKE '$name'";
            $result=$this->query($sql);
            if ($row=$this->next($result)) {
                return explode("','",preg_replace("/(enum|set)\('(.+?)'\)/","\\2",$row['Type']));
            }
            return "";
        }
        //_____________________________________________________________________________
    }
```

My Question: **How i can solve this problem, any suggestion ?**

**PHP Version 5.3.26**

Comment: what version of PHP is it? The `mysql` functions are deprecated and removed from PHP 7+

Comment: Database connection is not established. username and password values are wrong. check your db.php file for connection values

Comment: @RamRaider my PHP version is 5.3.26.

Comment: @Bhavik the username and password correct i've checked.

Comment: share the code you use to establish the db connection

Comment: Check ur phpmyadmin, make sure the user in ur connection script and password are correct

Comment: @RamRaider i've share my code.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi i've checked the user and password are correct.

Comment: Can you show ur dbmgr class?

Comment: At very top of ur Inc script add ob_start(); to suppress d header already sent warning on line 64. Then we continue to debug from there.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi i've share `dbmngr.php` class.

Comment: Your `DbMgr` class is `mysqli` but the error messages relate to `mysql` which is formed in the included file `db.php` - the problem lies in that file.. why include both mysql and mysqli connections?

Comment: i've solved with removing this line `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");` form second file `db.php` , 10x for all.